# Increase HtmlLogger output size

Tags: logging, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I'm running a big test on CUIT ( 20 methods ~ ) on long pages ( lots of forms , etc ) and my log is not covering all of it ! ( It stops around 3/4 of the 11th method )

Is there a way I can increase the size of the log ? I've searched on google but haven't found anything useful.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't the size of the log. There's no limit on the log size. The problem is the size of your computer's memory. The log is kept in memory until it's ready to be written, and is then written to disk.

One option is to reduce what you're logging. One way is to add this line near the top of your [TestMethod]:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.LoggerOverrideState = HtmlLoggerState.ErrorAndWarningOnlySnapshot;
```

Another way is to reduce the TraceLevel in the app.config:

```
<configuration> 
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
        <add name="EqtTraceLevel" value="1" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

These probably don't help, since you clearly want to capture the full logs. Therefore you probably need to break the tests methods into separate test classes, and run them via an .orderedtest file.

Comment: There is no way to write it dinamically ? I can't ( or don't know ) if I can split my tests since I'm fetching data from a csv.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way (other than finishing a test) to flush the log output to disk.I'm not sure what reading a data source has to do with it, unless you're reading LOTS of data that's persisted from one to the next. I was going to say (before pressing enter to create a paragraph caused this to post requiring me to edit it) that if you do have lots of data (or even if you don't) you can always just re-read the data. A way to do that is to put the reads in a method and call the method from each test case.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You said about putting the reads in a method and call it for each test case. How could I do that ?

Comment: 1. Create an IO class.
2. Add a method to open each database/XML/flat file/whatever, one method per resource. Do NOT use a StreamReader. 
3. Add a method to close each resource, one method per resource.
4. Add at least one read method for each resource. Any processing for the input can be done here if it makes sense.
5. In your Coded Test, call each method as needed to retrieve your data.
We're off topic here. if you have more questions not related to HTMLLogger Size, post a new question.
If you think I've helped, be sure to mark my answer as your answer.